# Typescript array of function traversal question

Tags: arrays, typescript, function, loops, functional-programming

My program has a place where many conditions are checked.

As opposed to writing a big `if(conditionOne || conditionTwo || ...)` type of expressions, I decided to define an array of filters like so:

```
const filters: Array<(err: MyError) => boolean> = [
      (e: MyError) => e.checkSomething(),
      (e: MyError) => e.checkSomethingElse,
      (e: MyError) => e.checkSomethingYetAgain()
    ];
```

I then traverse it like so:

```
for (const key in filters) {
      if (filters[key](err)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
return false;
```

I feel like there's a more functional way to express this (since now, in my opinion, this looks too imperative), but I'm not sure how it looks.
Thanks!

Comment: "better" how? We need an objective way of measuring answers, or the question will be closed as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: What I'm looking for is a more functional way to express this idea, since the way I've described looks very imperative.

Comment: For instance, is it "better" or "more functional" to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)?

Comment: I would say that using `reduce` does look fore functional to me, however, I'm not sure how exactly to write it, since calling `reduce` on my array of functions returns a function but not a value.

Comment: Calling reduce returns whatever you want it to return, namely, what you assign to the accumulator. I encourage you to [read the linked article in its entirety](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#How_reduce\(\)_works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
function makeErrorFilter(filters: Array<(err: MyError) => boolean>) {
  return (err: MyError) => !!filters.find(filter => filter(err));
}

const errorFilter = makeErrorFilter([
  (e: MyError) => e.checkSomething(),
  (e: MyError) => e.checkSomethingElse,
  (e: MyError) => e.checkSomethingYetAgain()
]);
```